# SQL Server loop and insert in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to run a loop in SQL. Google this is a little hard for some odd reason. In SQL Server I just put this is in the query editor in SQL Server Managment Studio

```
DECLARE @z_start INT
SET @z_start = 0
DECLARE @z_end INT
SET @z_end = 0

WHILE (@z_start <= 14) BEGIN
    IF(@z_start != 0 AND @z_end != 14)
        WHILE (@z_end <= 14) BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [campusMap].[dbo].[zoom_levels] ([zoom_start],[zoom_end]) VALUES (@z_start,@z_end)
            SET @z_end = @z_end + 1
        END
        SET @z_start = @z_start + 1
    END
END
```

All I want to do is to set the zoom_start and zoom_end  so (0,0) to (14,14) skipping only (0,14) as that is already in the table.

I think I'm close.  Anyone know where it's off?  Thank you.
Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of doing a nested loop and inserted each row at a time, you can use a CTE (Or a pre-existing numbers table) and add all the rows you need at once:

```
;WITH Numbers (Number) AS 
(
    SELECT 0 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 + Number FROM Numbers 
    WHERE 1 + Number <= 14
)
INSERT INTO [campusMap].[dbo].[zoom_levels] ([zoom_start],[zoom_end])
SELECT n1.Number, n2.Number 
FROM
    Numbers n1 CROSS JOIN
    Numbers n2
WHERE
    NOT (n1.Number = 0 AND n2.Number = 14)
```

Set-based operations in SQL are usually cleaner and easier to understand than procedural, row-by-row approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You are not reinitializing `@z_end` to zero after the first loop. Do

```
DECLARE @z_start INT
SET @z_start = 0
DECLARE @z_end INT
SET @z_end = 0
WHILE (@z_start <= 14) BEGIN
    IF(@z_start != 0 AND @z_end != 14)
        WHILE (@z_end <= 14) BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [campusMap].[dbo].[zoom_levels] ([zoom_start],[zoom_end]) VALUES (@z_start,@z_end)
            SET @z_end = @z_end + 1
        END
        SET @z_start = @z_start + 1
        SET @z_end = 0
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into [campusMap].[dbo].[zoom_levels] ([zoom_start],[zoom_end])
select T1.N, T2.N
from 
  (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14)) as T1(N)
cross join
  (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14)) as T2(N)
where not (T1.N = 0 and T2.N = 14)
```